Create MatchingEngineIndex taking forever
I'm creating an index in VertexAI using the command aiplatform.MatchingEngineIndex.create_tree_ah_index and it's taking forever. Still running right now and its' over an hour. I only have 2000 embeddings in my file which is uploaded to Google Cloud Storage. This command rand fine with ~200 embeddings, so I scaled it up.
I'm wondering ... what is governing this process that I can make it go faster?

I have extra data in the file above just id and embedding. Is this slowing it down?
Could sharding the file help? How big is a good size?
Is there a compression option for the file? would that help?
Is there a way to put more compute behind this? I haven't specified anything
I'm using moderately high dimensionality (768) would that be impacting this?
Does the approximate_neighbors_count impact the runtime?
Any options I can specify here?

I can't find any guidance on why this would be taking forever or what I can do about it.
